# Create Update product REST API magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, product, api

I got below error on my rest API on magento2.1

```
{
    "message": "%fieldName is a required field.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "product"
    }
}
```

My URL is: `https://XXX/rest/all/V1/products`

I want to add or edit the product in both POST and PUT method got the same error. my code to create/update is

```
 "product": {
        "sku": "B201-SKU",
        "name": "B202",
        "price": 30.00,
        "status": 1,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "attribute_set_id":4,
        "weight": 1
    }
```

Also, use postman and set authentication  on it, GET method is ok but PUT and POST gets error

Comment: any body knows?

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be missing opening / closing brackets. Try this -

```
{
    "product": {
    "sku": "B201-SKU",
    "name": "B202",
    "price": 30.00,
    "status": 1,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "attribute_set_id":4,
    "weight": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: No, still get same error...